# How to Optimise the Insert statement

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my code to do the insert in my DB :

```
  private void saveAllBatchDetail(List<ReportingDetail> reportingDetails) {

        EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO %s (col,col2,col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?.....)", ReportingDetail.class.getAnnotation(Table.class).name());

        try (Connection connection = info.getDataSource().getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (ReportingDetail row : reportingDetails) {
                statement.clearParameters();
                statement.setInt(1, row.getQuantity());
                statement.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(row.getDate()));
                statement.setFloat(3, row.getId());
               ..... so on ma be 50 more columns 

                statement.addBatch();
                if ((counter + 1) % 500 == 0 || (counter + 1) == reportingDeliveryDetails.size()) {
                    statement.executeBatch();
                    statement.clearBatch();
                }
                counter++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What's is the best way to insert so i don't have manually do the parsing, as i have write for each columns i,e  `statement.setInt(1, row.getQuantity())`?

Comment: Do you refer to the code snippet? What parsing are you doing exactly?

Comment: @aled i am writing these statement manually `statement.setInt(1, row.getQuantity());` , is better way to do it

Comment: you would  have to write some mapping class that takes your input parameters, converts to a specific type if needed, then call the setXXX methods.  Not really less work.  There is no automatic way.  How would PDBC know what parameters to use?

Comment: if i have 10000 columns and do this insert ? So i have to manually to it ?

Comment: Ehrm, it appears you are using JPA and try very hard to work around that, why? Not to mention the errors you have in your code to start with. Instead of all that cruft just do `entityManager.persist(row)`. Replace `executeBatch` and `clearBatch` with `entityManager.flush()` and `entityManager.clear()`.

Comment: @M.Deinum i can't use `@Trancational` in my method directly it's call via protected method

Comment: Where did I mention `@Transactional`? You can wrap the method call in a `TransactionTemplate` if needed. But still I don't get where that transaction suddenly comes from I now where mentioned it, nor does your code show one (and there will be one somewhere on your toplevel method).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for suggesting `TransactionTemplate` i am able to do via `entitymanager.presist`.